# Cannot add new line each time writing input to a text file

Tags: php

As you see, I already had "\n" in the end of $outputString, but all the inputs in the text file are on the same line. What happens here?

```
$fopen = fopen("order/order.txt", 'ab');
$outputString = date('H:i, jS F Y')."\t".$tireQty."\t".$oilQty."\t".$sparkQty."\n";
fwrite($fopen, $outputString, strlen($outputString));
fclose($fopen);
```

Comment: Try to change `. "\n"` to this `. PHP_EOL` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Try using `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: What are you using to view the output file with? If you are on Windows and using a poor quality text editor (read: notepad.exe) the `\n` line endings will not be handled correctly as it expects `\r\n`.

Comment: thanks guys. Both PHP_EOL and "\r\n" works well !
@MichaelBerkowski: I use notepad so I guess that the cause.